# Codeigniter 4 Shield: How to issue an access token

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4, codeigniter-restapi

I'm starting to work with [Codeigniter 4 Shield](https://codeigniter4.github.io/shield/).

I added this piece of code to my `app/Config/Routes.php` file.

```
$routes->get('/access/token', static function() {
    $token = auth()->user()->generateAccessToken(service('request')->getVar('token_name'));

    return json_encode(['token' => $token->raw_token]);
});
```

When I try to access the route in my web browser using the URL `https://example.com/access/token`, I obtain the error:

```
Call to a member function generateAccessToken() on null
```

produced by the line of code below:

```php
$token = auth()->user()->generateAccessToken(service('request')->getVar('token_name'));
```

##### Background information:

- I have installed [Codeigniter 4 Shield](https://codeigniter4.github.io/shield/) using Composer, ran the respective database migrations, and everything else works fine.
- My Codeigniter 4 Shield *'login'* and *'register'* pages work fine.

*How can I load `generateAccessToken()` automatically in the `app/Config/Routes.php` file?*

Answer (score 2):

You need to submit the login credentials (email & password) along with your HTTP `POST` request to help identify the User requesting the access token. Otherwise, `auth()->user()` is empty, hence the error.

To generate an access token, you need to first authenticate the User.

**For example: (Using `email` & `password`)**

1. Define your *'access token'* route. Notice the use of `->post(...)` instead of `->get(...)`.

*File: app/Config/Routes.php*

```php
$routes->post('auth/token', '\App\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::accessToken');
```

2. Define your Controller method that will handle the *'access token'* generation.  Read: [Issuing the Tokens](https://codeigniter4.github.io/shield/guides/mobile_apps/)

*File: app/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php*

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;

class LoginController extends BaseController
{
    public function accessToken()
    {
        // Validate credentials
        $rules = [
            'email' => [
                'label' => 'Auth.email',
                'rules' => config('AuthSession')->emailValidationRules,
            ],
            'password' => [
                'label' => 'Auth.password',
                'rules' => 'required',
            ],
        ];

        if (!$this->validate($rules)) {
            return $this->response
                ->setJSON(['errors' => $this->validator->getErrors()])
                ->setStatusCode(422);
        }

        if (auth()->loggedIn()) {
            auth()->logout();
        }

        // Attempt to login
        $result = auth()->attempt([
            'email' => $this->request->getPost('email'),
            'password' => $this->request->getPost('password')
        ]);
        if (!$result->isOK()) {
            return $this->response
                ->setJSON(['error' => $result->reason()])
                ->setStatusCode(401);
        }
        // Generate token and return to client
        $token = auth()->user()->generateAccessToken($this->getDeviceName());

        return $this->response
            ->setJSON(['token' => $token->raw_token]);
    }


    public function getDeviceName()
    {
        $agent = $this->request->getUserAgent();

        if ($agent->isBrowser()) {
            $currentAgent = $agent->getBrowser() . ' ' . $agent->getVersion();
        } elseif ($agent->isRobot()) {
            $currentAgent = $agent->getRobot();
        } elseif ($agent->isMobile()) {
            $currentAgent = $agent->getMobile();
        } else {
            $currentAgent = 'Unidentified User Agent';
        }


        return $agent->getPlatform() . " - " . $currentAgent;
    }
}
```

3. Protect your `/api` routes using the `$filters` setting on `app/Config/Filters.php`. Read: [Protecting Routes](https://codeigniter4.github.io/shield/guides/api_tokens/)

- Exclude your *'access token'* (`"auth/token"`) route together with all API routes (`"api/*"`)  from the global `"session"` & `"toolbar"` filters.

*File: app/Config/Filters.php*

```php
<?php

// ...

class Filters extends BaseConfig
{
    // ...

    public array $globals = [
        'before' => [
            'session' => ['except' => [
                "login*",
                "register",
                "auth/a/*",
                "auth/token",
                "api/*"
            ]],
        ],
        'after' => [
            'toolbar' => ['except' => ["auth/token", "api/*"]],
        ],
    ];

    // ...

    public array $filters = [
        'tokens' => ['before' => ["api/*"]],
    ];
}
```

4. Make a one-time initial HTTP `POST` request to the `auth/token` route to receive the *'access token'*. Upon receiving the token, store it with the client. I.e: in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://your-site-domain.com/auth/token",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        "email": "USER-EMAIL-ADDRESS-HERE",
        "password": "USER-PASSWORD-HERE",
    },
    success: function (response) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    },
});
```

5. You may now send the received/stored access token using the `Authorization` header along with all your other protected API HTTP requests in your application without reauthenticating the user. i.e:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://your-site-domain.com/api/rest/v1/employees",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader(
            "Authorization",
            "Bearer " + window.localStorage.getItem('token')
        );
    },
    data: {},
    success: function (response) {
        // Use the response here on success.
        // I.e: listing all employees in a table.
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    },
});
```